# Question from exam

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V is a complex vector space and if $A$ is a linear transformation such that spectar of $A=\{5,6\}$. Prove that $(A-5I)^{n-1}\circ(A-6I)^{n-1}=O$. And $n=\dim V$.

My teacher said that when you do not know on $n$-dimensional space you put down on 2 space that is easy, and I use that $n=2$. Now I know the spectrum of $(A-5I)=\{0,1\}$ and the spectrum of $(A-6I)=\{-1,0\}$ now I define linear transformation for some vector $(A-5I)(x,y)=(0,y)$ and $(A-6I)(x,y)=(-x,0)$ from here we can see that $\operatorname{im}(A-6I)=\ker(A-5I)$ so than $(A-5I)\circ(A-6I)=O$, but what do you think is that  enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot define the linear transformation. Every square matrix satisfies its characteristic equaltion. Note that $5$ cannot be a root of order $n$ since $6$ is also a root. Hence $5$ is a root of order at most $n-1$. same thing is true of $6$. Hence $(\lambda -5)^{n-1} (\lambda -6)^{n-1}$ is divisible by the characteristic polynomial. Hence $(A -5I)^{n-1} (A-6I)^{n-1}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the spectrum of $A$ is $\{5,6\}$, the char. polynomial $p$ of $A$ is given by

$p(z)=(z-5)^k(z-6)^l$,

with $k,l \ge 1$ and $k+l=n$. By Cayley - Hamilton:

$0=p(A)=(A-5I)^k(A-6I)^l$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: I see that, then for every number of k and l will be zero in my case k=n-1 and l=n-1